# Broke ubuntu while uninstalling app

Tags: 18.04, package-management, uninstall

I tried to uninstall unity-tweak-tools by the command line but while looking at removal process, I saw that it was removing way more than what I wanted. I don't know why, but it started to remove many things that had nothing to do with the app I wanted to uninstall. 
Now my desktop is missing many programs I used daily. I can't even find "Software" to reinstall what is now missing.
Is there a way to repair what is missing or am I forced to do a clean reinstall?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. Advice: Always read your proposed removals carefully before agreeing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling unity-tweak-tools from a command line? This should reinstall the other packages along with it. As far as removing ONLY the tweak-tools package, I'm not sure how to do that.

delta1071

Comment: No. The line I used to remove the app was "sudo apt remove unity-tweak-tool 3.0" and I think it was interpreted as "remove unity then remove tweak-tool". It started removing things and the estimated time to remove was very long. This made me realize that it was doing way more than what I wanted. I saw then that it started to remove apache. I hit ctrl-z immediately by not without damages.

Comment: The command "sudo apt remove unity-tweak-tool 3.0" tells apt to remove only that package.  Spaces between each package name tell apt that multiple packages are to be removed. What's the output of your original command?

Comment: I didn't write it down, and I won't run it again to check but the effects were way deeper that the removal of unity-tweak-tool. As I wrote in the previous comment, apache was being removed, I had to reinstall audacity, clementine, keypassxc. Some apps are no longer available in the list like "software" that is used to add or remove apps.